# How to fix XML comment warnings automatically?

Tags: c#, roslyn

In my C# xml comments, I have many of these warnings:

> CS1574 XML comment has cref attribute 'days' that could not be resolved

Where the `<see>` element has been used instead of `<paramref>`. An easy mistake.

```
/// <summary>
/// Add <see cref="days"/> days to <see cref="date"/>.
/// </summary>
public static double AddDays(double date, int days)
{
    return DateTime.FromOADate(date).AddDays(days).ToOADate();
}
```

How can I fix them all? There about 1000 across 200 files so I don't want to do it by hand. A find-and-replace wouldn't work, because that would break at least as many legitimate uses of `<see>`.

Would the new C# Roslyn code analysis API help? I could imagine code that finds these kind of warnings, tests if the broken target is really the name of a parameter, and if so makes the edit to `paramref`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a Find and Replace with a regular expression that only matches if the cref in the see tag matches a parameter in the parameter list.

Here is a very ugly regex that should work:

```
((?:///\s*\<summary\>\s*\n)(?:\s*?///.*\n)*?\s*///.*?\<)see\s+cref(?=(=\"(:?.*)\"\s*/\>.*\n(?:///.*\n)*\s*///\s*\</summary\>[\s\n]*.*\((?:[^\)]|\n)*\3\b(?:[^\)]|\n)*\)[\s\n]*\{))
```

Then use this replace text:

```
$1paramref name
```

The regex starts a capture to get everything before the text to be replaced, then looks for the start of a summary block.  Once it's found a summary block then it goes through the summary block lines and looks for a `see`. If it finds one it captures the cref of the `see`. Then it begins looking ahead. It looks for the end of the summary block, then optional blank lines, then it looks for one more lines that look kind of like the header of a method definition. (Any sequence followed by parenthesized arguments list, followed by a {) Inside the matched parentheses, it looks for the cref from the see tag (the `\3\b` backref with a word boundary).

If the match is successful, the replace text writes out the captured prologue text, then it switches the `see cref` to `paramref name`.  It doesn't need to write the rest of the text because we used a lookahead group to match the parameter name.

Some caveats

1. You'll probably need to run this many times over the same source
2. My Visual Studio (2012) isn't doing well with the capture reference in
   the replacement text, hopefully yours handles it better.

Overall like a lot of regex based solutions, you can use it to do most of the work and then clean up any misses by hand.